# Android Studio Gradle build "apply plugin: 'com.android.library'": aar missing files

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm using Android Studio and building Android library project, so I distribute `aar` file. And to be more specific I just distribute the jar inside (yes- customers still using Eclipse so I combine manually the `jar` with manifest, res etc well known procedure).

This is my Gradle build script (regular default...):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // Ain't applicationIdNot
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/../lib'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile '...'
}
```

The problem is that: Under one java package alongside regular java classes I have `ttf` font files. This is due to historical reasons and now the project complexity not allowing to make changes and move them to where they actually need to be.

Well - The jar missing these files. How to implement the build process such the `jar` inside the `arr` will include these files - Because after all - It's regular archive and those file are in the file tree already compressed into the `jar`.

Thanks,

Comment: Host thefonts and loadem dynamically. Like google fonts

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thanks, I don't want to bay pass this issue rather then to understand how to customize the build script. Right now what I'm doing is decompressing the jar, add the files and compress manually back to jar using terminal.

Comment: In my case it was that I forgot to add the apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' when I modularised the project which caused the kotlin files not to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify to include the files in your `sourceSets` closure

```
// if you want to include the files in your aar
android {
    ...
    sourceSets {
        main {
            resources.includes = [ '**/mySweetFont.ttf' ]
        }        
    }
}

// to include in your jar
sourceSets {
    main {
        resources.includes = [ '**/mySweetFont.ttf' ]
    }        
}
```

This will place the files at the root of the artifact produced.  For the `jar` you *may* need to specify the `sourceSets` closure twice once inside `android` closure and again after the `android` closure

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But this not works. Note that the location of the tff files is inside some java package.

Comment: I opened more specific question for this because your answer gave me focus on what to concentrate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208453/android-gradle-aar-build-include-exclude-files-from-jar