# Android Gradle library build: Include & exclude files from the jar inside the generated aar

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I exporting Android library via building `aar` with Gradle, and I have requirements for the `jar` inside the `aar`: Basically I need the jar to reflect following files structure that already exist in the project (jpeg files should be inside java package alongside `.class` files):

```
project_name
           |
           module_name
                     |
                     src
                       |
                       main
                          |
                          java
                             |
                             package_to_include
                                              |
                                              java_files
                                              jpeg_files
                             package_to_exclude
```

This is the relevant part from `build.gradle` script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'    
android {
    ... 
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src/main/java'
                exclude 'package_to_exclude/**'
                resources.includes = [ 'package_to_include/*.jpeg' ]
            }
            resources {
                srcDir 'src/../lib'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result: The exclude part works, the include not: In the jar inside package_to_include there are only the java source code files as `.class` files. The jpeg's not in the jar at all.

By the way I'm not totally familiar with the double astrix (**) operator. Maybe this is the direction for solution?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspect the `**` is the missing component. Guessing the path to your include is probably missing the `src/main/java` prefix to the `package_to_include`.

`**` means any folder reclusively.  So for example:

```
src/main/java/package_to_include/image.jpg
src/main/res/image.jpg
// both would match
**/image.jpg
```

Also this line is weird `srcDir 'src/../lib'`  because its the same as `srcDir 'lib'`

Comment: 1. Because of the `srcDir 'src/main/java'` I can next use in the scope only from `package_to_include`.

Comment: 2. Still I don't get why it's not working because how should I use the includes?